# Selenium finding web Elements using x and y co ordinates

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

so far I am aware how to click on web element passing x and y co ordinates, but is there anyway to find a web element by passing x and y co ordinates . For example if I pass (400,400), is there a method to find if some web element present at that co ordinates and returns me that Web Element. I am trying to find this from quite a while, but no luck. Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is No.

Comment: I don't think so if that is possible so far now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is not the good approach, but if you know the exact coordinate of web element then you can try something like this.

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
Object obj = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.elementFromPoint(342, 89);");
if (obj instanceof WebElement) {
      ((WebElement) obj).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try build a anonymous function lib that return an array which a x,y pos map,then,give a range to test your x,y in map,some elements like div,or img,could be found